# How to use NavigationLink to detect name of click NavigationView item

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

How can the destination of a `NavigationLink` can modified to detect which item within a list was clicked? An `if` statement of some sort would be very helpful but all items currently do the same thing.

```
import SwiftUI

let textTitle = NSLocalizedString("PageTitle", comment: "")
let textItemA = NSLocalizedString("ItemA", comment: "")
let textItemB = NSLocalizedString("ItemB", comment: "")
let textItemC = NSLocalizedString("ItemC", comment: "")

struct ItemMain: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
}

let myItems: [MyItem] = [
    MyItem(name: textItemA),
    MyItem(name: textItemB),
    MyItem(name: textItemC)]

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingAlert = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List(myItems) { myItem in
                NavigationLink(destination: MyDetailView(myItem: myItem)) {
                    Text(myItem.name)
                }
            }

            .navigationBarTitle(textTitle)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct MyDetailView: View {
    var myItem: MyItem

    var body: some View {
        Text(myIem.name)
    }
}
```

Comment: You are sending myItem to your DetailView. You can access all variables of that object there and identiy it with their unique id.

Comment: @davidev I don't want all items to navigate there. I want a specific item to navigate there, and a different specific item to launch an alert dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I customized your MyItem model as it is not provided by you

```
enum MyItemType {
    case navigation
    case alert
}

struct MyItem: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    var type: MyItemType = .alert
}
```

And made changed to your ContentView

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingAlert = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            listView
                .navigationBarTitle(textTitle)
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showingAlert) {
            //Customise your alert according to your need
            Alert(title: Text("Alert"))
        }
    }
    
    private var listView: some View {
        List(myItems) { myItem in
            if myItem.type == .navigation {
                NavigationLink(destination: MyDetailView(myItem: myItem)) {
                    Text(myItem.name)
                }
            } else {
                Button(action: {
                    self.showingAlert = true
                }) {
                    Text(myItem.name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And lastly your `myItems` array:

```
let myItems: [MyItem] = [
    MyItem(name: textItemA, type: MyItemType.navigation),
    MyItem(name: textItemB),
    MyItem(name: textItemC)
]
```

Comment: `.alert(isPresented: $showingAlert)` returns: `The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions`

Comment: I would suggest moving ListView logic to a separate function, that returns the desired view.

Comment: not sure of the best way to do this when the List needs to be inside a NavigationView

Comment: @MacaronLover I have edited my answer based on my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if` statement inside the `ForEach` to specify special cases:

```
List(myItems) { myItem in
    if (myItem.name == "ItemA") //<<< Here goes your if 
    {
        NavigationLink(destination: MyDetailView(myItem: myItem)) {
            Text(myItem.name)
        }
     }
     else 
     {
         //show your alert here
```